# Adding to an array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, position

I have an array `int Stack[]` of size 5. I want to implement a method `Push(value)` that will push *value* into the last available slot of the array. Example: if array is empty and I use `Push(1)`, now there is a 1 on position 0 of the array; but if the array has 3 values and I use `Push(1)`, there will be a 1 on position 3 (since the array starts at 0, for a total of 4 values in the array). How may I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
public class Stack{
    int items[];
    int top;
    
    public Stack(int size){
       items=new int[size];
       top=0;
    }
   
   public void Push(int val){
         if(!IsFull()){
             items[top++]=val;
         }     
   }
  
   public int Pop(){
      if(!IsEmpty()){
          return items[--top];
      }else{
          //-1 is for invalid op or just you can chech before calling Pop()
          //is stack empty or not
          return -1;

      }
   }

   public bool IsFull()=>top==items.Length;
   public bool IsEmpty()=>top==0;

}
```

Comment: This is literally exactly what i need; even with a future method I need. Thanks!

Comment: I'd `throw new InvalidOperationException("Stack is full")` in `Push()` if `IsFull()` is true, just to be on the safe side. Otherwise you can't differentiate a successful call from an unsuccessful one. That could result in some hard-to-diagnose errors. Same for `Pop()` underflow.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you have `List<T>`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0

Of course you can do that with an array as well, but that would mean that you have to make a new array for each `Push()` execution, which is completely unnecessary when you can use a list

Comment: Due to the nature of the assignment, I cannot use List and must use an array